# Android Studio Modules are not updated when switching git branches

Tags: android, git, git-branch

When I create new branch 'Branch1' and then add new module 'branch1' to it and commit the changes. Then when I switch to the 'master' branch the module is still visible as seen in the image below.

[image]

I can solve the problem by refreshing the Gradle from `View > Tools Windows > Gradle`, then right click and then Reload Gradle Project. Or using Invalidate cache restart, but is slower than simply refreshing the gradle.

***But is there more generic solution, that does that gradle sync automatically, when switching branches or stashes?***

[image]